# JavaScript: как найти объект в памяти по значению ключа

Tags: javascript, объекты, память

Можно ли найти объект в памяти, если я его никуда (*например в массив*) не сохраняю. Код:

```
const testing = () => {
    class Obj {
        constructor(id, title = 'Title') {
            this.id = id,
            this.title = title
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const article = new Obj(i);
        document.writeln(article.id, ' ', article.title, ';')
    }
}
testing();
```

Есть ли соответствующие объекты, например:
`{id : 5, title : "Title},` и можно ли их как-то извлечь по id?

Или старые уничтожаются в строке `const article = new Obj(i);`

Comment: ну у вас есть переменная `article`, где хранится значение `{id: 5, title: 'Title'}`

Comment: У JavaScript в отличии от с++ нет понятия  адрес в памяти или ключ в памяти и т. п. Ссылки - существуют, взятие адреса существует - но получить адрес явно, или обратится по адресу явно возможности нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как создаваемые объекты нигде не сохраняются, непосредственный доступ к ним можно осуществить только внутри цикла **после** строки `const article = new Obj(i);`.

При переходе к следующей итерации ссылка на созданный объект теряется, следовательно, теряется и возможность доступа к нему.

В последствии созданный объект может быть собран сборщиком мусора.